# WebStorm does not resolve aliases when Webpack is configured from Expo's createWebpackConfigAsync

Tags: webpack, expo, webstorm

I have a React Native Web project using Expo. I have added [aliases](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver#editors-autocompletion) to make import statements easier to read and manage. Expo, as part of its configuration, has its own Webpack configuration, which can be modified using the [documentation found here](https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-webpack/). This works, and the aliases resolve correctly when the project is built/run. However, WebStorm fails to resolve the aliases in it's intellisense after.

**For example:**

```
import userSlice from "@store/User";  // Hovering over "@store/User" will show warning: Module is not installed
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
let path = require("path");
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require("@expo/webpack-config");

const aliases = {
    '@store': path.resolve(__dirname, '/src/store/'),
};

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
    env.mode = "development"
    const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);

    config.resolve.alias = {
        ...aliases,
        ...config.resolve.alias,
    };

    return config
};
```

There is no output in the Event Log that indicates an error.

Thinking that the `env` properties might somehow be different, I also tried manually setting these to the same values that are present when building from a terminal. I've also tried creating a simple Webpack config without Expo, and WebStorm does correctly resolve that.

Answer (score 1):

Can be related to [WEB-36182](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36182); you can check your idea.log file (**Help > Show Log in ...**) to see if any errors are thrown on webpack evaluation.
I'd suggest trying a workaround suggested for VSCode (configure the path mapping in `jsconfig.json`) - this should work in WebStorm